# i am writing login and logout system and i want to handle error on frontend and manipulate dom using it

Tags: javascript

i am writing login and logout system and i want to handle error on frontend and manipulate dom using it. here in my code i want to send status and error to front end and manipulate the dom using it. so i want to know how to send my error data to front end and how to handle error on frontend
the code i am using below is for my registeration page

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const emailValue = req.body.email;
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const newUser = {
      email: emailValue,
      password: hashPassword,
    };
    const {value , error} = validateUser(newUser);
    if (error) {
      res.status(404).send("")
    } else {
      const user = users.find((u) => {
        if (u.email === req.body.email) {
          return u;
        }
      });
      if (user) {
        res.status(404).send("")
      } else {
        users.push(newUser);
        res.status(200).send();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404);
  }
});
```

Comment: so what not work?

Comment: how to i send my error data after res.status to frontend and how to handle them on frontend

Comment: @ tdashby87 by calling `.send("")`? isn't it what you're doing?